# Python automated test that involve firewall or blocking IP

Tags: python, macos, networking, firewall

I have to write some specific automated tests using Python that should block all outbound traffic to a certain host or ip range. On windows I achieved this via the windows hosts file and the effect is the desired one but on Mac OSX this does not work as somehow the hosts file is ignored.

How could I do this programmatically? [Netfilter](https://github.com/jlaine/python-netfilter) but the lack of documentation and examples is keeping me from using it. Could anyone give me an idea? for example how i could block access to google.com

Comment: This sounds like quite a heavy duty integration test. Are you sure you need this?

Comment: sadly yeah, it's necessary. Thing is, it's easy to do this on windows and Linux but seems very difficult on OSX this is why I need some help